# Multivariate Normal changes value of variable in PyMC

Tags: python, distribution, pymc

I might be doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is. I'm trying to reproduce some results from a real state dataset from Baton Rouge, LA. The original code is written in WinBUGS [here](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/data/BatonRougebinary.bug). There are some minor differences between the dataset used in the link above and the one I'm using right now. However, I think that is not significant. This is the code:

```
import pymc as pm, pandas as pd, numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from numpy.linalg import inv

# Loading dataset
df = pd.read_table('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=41us4HVj', sep=' ')

# Setting priors
beta = pm.Normal('beta', 0.0, 0.1, size=3)
mu = pm.Lambda('mu', lambda b=beta: 
               b[0]+b[1]*df['LivingArea']/1000.0+b[2]*df['Age'])
tau = pm.Gamma('tau', 0.1, 0.1)
phi = pm.Uniform('phi', 0.1, 10)

# Trying to build a covariate matrix
A = squareform(pdist(np.array(zip(df['Latitude'], df['Longitude']))))

# Using the powered exponential to obtain a precision matrix
precision = pm.Lambda('exp', lambda u=A, tau=tau, phi=phi, kappa=1: 
                                inv((1/tau)*np.exp(-(phi*u)**kappa)))
```

If I inspect the value of `mu`, I get this:

```
mu.value
Out[2]:
0     24.568272
1      2.909063
2     -2.778916
3     28.206696
4     -0.270571
5     -2.865153
6     14.158162
7     31.466438
8     44.681351
9     22.191397
10    -6.412350
11    11.709424
12    25.453254
13    24.366674
14    34.711048
...
55    24.625763
56    21.763089
57    65.108136
58    15.428714
59    20.992329
60    36.384037
61    16.730507
62    23.021763
63    54.887747
64    30.612696
65    52.685840
66    59.612372
67    18.822422
68    18.940658
69    72.678188
Length: 70, dtype: float64
```

However, after running MvNormal, the value of `mu` is changed:

```
w = pm.MvNormal('w', mu, precision)

mu.value
Out[4]:
0    -107.913779
1      -1.243466
2       8.283926
3      26.412651
4       1.806728
5      -1.300734
6     -80.657396
7      71.614343
8      -3.817774
9     -10.283683
10     -3.804962
11      8.639403
12     18.927553
13    -10.004095
14    -37.431770
...
55    88.612179
56    18.011459
57    -7.421157
58     7.974531
59    -3.697444
60   -17.520367
61    36.453531
62   -39.235745
63    -6.701737
64    68.672902
65   -44.040923
66    11.826075
67   -21.995198
68   -15.886362
69     4.653335
Length: 70, dtype: float64
```

By the way, this only happens to `mu`. The precision variable remains the same.

Did I make a mistake?

**UPDATE**:

Already [filed](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/603) an issue on GitHub. After further inspection, the culprit seems to be the pd.Series object that is used in the `mu` variable. If I convert or remove the Series, `mu` won't change after calling MvNormal.

Thanks!

Comment: I see this strange behavior, too.  It seems like a bug to me, so I suggest you [file an issue with the pymc-devs on their github](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues).

Comment: Thank you for reproducing this. I will file an issue.

Comment: PyMC 2 is not compatible with Pandas data structures (or is it the other way around?). I would just pass the value of the data frame. PyMC 3 will support Pandas.

Comment: Of course, that works. If you want, you can put your comment as an answer. By the way, is PyMC3 ready to be used as a stable release?